# Timeline in tikz. Prevent nodes from overlaping

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, timeline

I am trying to create timeline template that looks like this:

[image: example]

It looked ok but when I added `bignode`s everything started overlaping (bignodes are the text nodes to be on the right of corresponding squarenodes)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
squarenode/.style={rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, ultra thick, minimum size=10mm},
roundnode/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, ultra thick, minimum size=1mm},
bignode/.style={rectangle, text width=20em, draw=blue!10, fill=blue!0, ultra thick, minimum size=60mm},
]
%Nodes

\node[roundnode]        (t1)        {};
\node[roundnode]        (t2)   [right=of t1]     {};
\node[roundnode]        (t3)   [right=of t2]     {};
\node[roundnode]        (t4)   [right=of t3]     {};
\node[roundnode]        (t5)   [right=of t4]     {};

\node[squarenode]       (t1u)   [above=of t1]   {1};
\node[squarenode]       (t3u)   [above=of t3]   {3};
\node[squarenode]       (t5u)   [above=of t5]   {5};

\node[squarenode]       (t2d)   [below=of t2]   {2};
\node[squarenode]       (t4d)   [below=of t4]   {4};


\node[bignode]          (t1b)   [right=of t1u]  {Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius};
\node[bignode]          (t2b)   [right=of t2d]  {Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius};
\node[bignode]          (t3b)   [right=of t3u]  {Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eiusx};
\node[bignode]          (t4b)   [right=of t4d]  {Nemo enim ipsam};
\node[bignode]          (t5b)   [right=of t5u]  {Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius};




%Lines
\draw[-] (t1.east) -- (t2.west);
\draw[-] (t2.east) -- (t3.west);
\draw[-] (t3.east) -- (t4.west);
\draw[-] (t4.east) -- (t5.west);

\draw[-] (t1.north) -- (t1u.south);
\draw[-] (t3.north) -- (t3u.south);
\draw[-] (t5.north) -- (t5u.south);

\draw[-] (t2.south) -- (t2d.north);
\draw[-] (t4.south) -- (t4d.north);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
xxx\\
\begin{tikzpicture}


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete, compilable document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were almost there. I just added some distances and anchors.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
squarenode/.style={rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, ultra thick, minimum size=10mm},
roundnode/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, ultra thick, minimum size=1mm},
bignode/.style={rectangle, text width=20em, draw=blue!10, fill=blue!0, ultra thick, minimum size=60mm},
]
%Nodes

\node[roundnode]        (t1)        {};
\node[roundnode]        (t2)   [right=12em of t1]     {};
\node[roundnode]        (t3)   [right=12em of t2]     {};
\node[roundnode]        (t4)   [right=12em of t3]     {};
\node[roundnode]        (t5)   [right=12em of t4]     {};
\node[bignode]          (t1b)   [above right=5mm of t1,anchor=south west]  {Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius};
\node[bignode]          (t2b)   [below right=5mm of t2,anchor=north west]  {Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius};
\node[bignode]          (t3b)   [above right=5mm of t3,anchor=south west]  {Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eiusx};
\node[bignode]          (t4b)   [below right=5mm of t4,anchor=north west]  {Nemo enim ipsam};
\node[bignode]          (t5b)   [above right=5mm of t5,anchor=south west]  {Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius};

\node[squarenode]       (t1u)   [above=53 mm of t1]   {1};
\node[squarenode]       (t3u)   [above=53 mm of t3]   {3};
\node[squarenode]       (t5u)   [above=53 mm of t5]   {5};

\node[squarenode]       (t2d)   [below=53 mm of t2]   {2};
\node[squarenode]       (t4d)   [below=53 mm of t4]   {4};

%Lines
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using int(\X+1)] in {1,...,4}
{\draw[-] (t\X.east) -- (t\Y.west);}
\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
{
\ifodd\X
\draw[-] (t\X.north) -- (t\X u.south);
\else
\draw[-] (t\X.south) -- (t\X d.north);
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]