How would you create a timeline like the one below?

If you can make two of them(1914, 1915), I think I can make the rest.
We look forward to hearing back from you.

Something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/716440/36296 , https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462984/fancy-vertical-timeline  or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108774/how-can-i-make-a-standard-timeline?noredirect=1&lq=1  could get you started.

Welcome to TeX SE. Have you tried anything? Could you edit your post to include what you tried?

Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443014/timeline-in-tikz-prevent-nodes-from-overlaping and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676912/a-better-timeline-figure-using-tikz

unanswered duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386899/latex-packages-for-timelines

you could also do this with chronos. (disclaimer: I wrote it.)

or chronology, possibly.

Learn from https://tikz.dev/: (A) how to draw a line (x-axis), (B) how to place (empty) named nodes and draw their (circular) shape (circles), (C) place more nodes using anchor points (texts above and below), (D) learn about options like line width=, align=, fill= (color) etc.
